# Trigger to get table name

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have several bases on multiple servers with tables in the same column pattern.
What I need to do is create a trigger in the database to audit delete, update, insert is there any way I can dynamically leave the table name that was given update?
There is more than one table in each database to be monitored.
Every help is welcome

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. It sounds like you're talking about a DML trigger, which are specific to objects; so the trigger itself is on the table. Although the trigger doesn't "know" what table it's on, as such, as the trigger is specifically on a table just include the name of the table somewhere in your logic.

Comment: Yeah, you have to write/generate (at least) one `CREATE TRIGGER <X> ON <TableName> ...` statement for each table. Since you have to insert the table name there, you can also replace it lower down too, at the same time.

Comment: @Larnu is there the possibility of creating the DML trigger for the database? Because I have hundreds of table to be monitored

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have hundreds of table to be monitored and it is not feasible to create one by one

Comment: Yes, but whether you write those statements by hand or *generate them*, they have to be written and they already have to have the table name appear once at the top. Making it appear a second time lower down isn't a challenge. That's why you're not actually going to need a *function* or query within the trigger to discover the table name.

Comment: @FabianoCarvalho Hi, what is your SQL Server version ? If you are usin 2016 or 2017 look at this Temporal Table :) . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: To answer the question of *"possibility of creating the DML trigger for the database"*; no. DML statements affect data in objects, and so the DML triggers need to be on the objects themselves. Objects like `inserted` and `deleted` are defined by the object the Trigger is created on, so having a DML trigger at database level, for all objects, just wouldn't work. Triggers can be created at Database level, however, these are DDL triggers; so they "trigger" when a DDL change is made (like `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc, etc).

Comment: I would  suggest it's very unlikely you need a trigger on every table in your database; and that every trigger deos the "same" thing; if that what you believe you need this is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is your actual end goal here?

Answer (score 1):

You can check with this answer this might help you. Here I have given idea to create a trigger to monitor the update value in table.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229188/10532500

The output is as shown below of the trigger in the form of an audit table.

[image]